# LaTeX was not able to process the following string: b'lp'

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy, latex

I just begin with Python, scypi and matplotlib, I had copy this code:

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = stats.exponweib.rvs(a=1, c=2.09, scale=10.895, loc=0, size=2500)

plt.plot(data, stats.exponweib.pdf(data, *stats.exponweib.fit(data, 1, 1, scale=02, loc=0))

_ = plt.hist(data, bins = np.linspace(0, 16, 33), normed=True, alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

But it show an error:

```
'LaTeX was not able to process the following string: b'lp''
```

The file ...Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\matplotlibrc  show:
    `#text.usetex         : False`

os : windows 7
dis: winpython

What can I do? 
Thanks.

Comment: So you don't want to use latex. But you still get an error from latex although you did not specify anywhere in the script that you want to use it? How do you run your script?

Comment: Exactly I don't know what have to do this script with latex...Please see this picture: https://mega.nz/#!RyZDyIBL!7NB_WiBZVyJjqbPJMfl67RxPPtXte45XluTXhDOe408

Comment: Try to explicitely set `plt.rcParams["text.usetex"] = False` in the line below the pyplot import. This is to find out if the mechanism which starts latex comes from within the script or from outside.

Comment: It works!!  thank u very very much!

Comment: Well, this this means that the `text.usetex` is set to True somewhere outside. You may start by setting it to False explicitely by removing `#`, i.e. replacing the line `#text.usetex  : False` by `text.usetex : False` in the matplotlibrc file. It may also happen that your matplotlibrc file in use is actually in a different folder, which you can find out via `mpl.get_configdir()`.

Comment: Yes! It  was in another path...thanks for share your knowledge and be patient :)